# Run a remote .sh script from a local .bat script

Tags: bash, batch-file

I must write a script on windows (a bat file) which has to run a shell script on a Linux server. That would be the most linear way to achieve my goal, but I need to know if running a remote shell script from a local batch is even possible (given the server address and the credentials, of course), and then how that could be done.
Best regards.

Comment: From a bat file you should be able to curl an endpoint which triggers your sh file

Comment: How to you access the Linux system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user WinSCP
for example `put_file.bat`

"`C:\Program Files\WinSCP\winscp.com" /ini=nul /script="C:\Program Files\WinSCP\ticket_upload.sftp"`

for example ticket_upload.sftp

```
open sftp://login:password@192.168.0.9/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 d9:e6:2d:ab:0c:72:86:b8:5d:02:7c:c0:80:64:0d:7d"
cd /oracle/app/oracle/bb/abak
mput "C:\bb\abak\DBF.RAR"
call /oracle/app/oracle/extract_bb.sh
exit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it almost work, I only get an error with code 126 "Permission denied"  at the line where i call the .sh file, but I guess that I must solve this new problem with my admin. Thanks again Dmitry!

Comment: Than again, the call command does not really seems able to run a shell from remote; any other options?

Comment: @Matteo_B It is able. If it does not work for you, you will have to tell us more details.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl fair enough. The script works until the line where it calls the .sh script, claiming "Permission denied" and returning an error with code 126.

Comment: OK, so you still have the same problem you mention in the first comment. So did you talk to the admin? Does the script even have `x` permission? Can you execute `/oracle/app/oracle/extract_bb.sh` manually, if you login with an SSH terminal like PuTTY?

Comment: The problem evolved into another one, which is pretty off topic; in the end, @DmitryDemin 's advice, with some little adaptations, did the job. Thanks everyone.